# How to create dynamic variables in Java?

Tags: java, strong-typing, dynamic-typing

For example, in [Haxe](https://haxe.org/) I can create strictly typed variables:
`var a:Float = 1.1;` or `var b:String = "hello"` and also dynamic, if needed:

`var d:Dynamic = true; 
d = 22; 
d = "hi";`

How do I create this kind of variables in Java?

Comment: `Object` I think is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

```
Object d = true; 
d = 22; 
d = "hi";
```

and you can use `instanceof` operator to check which type of data `d` is holding

```
Object d = true; 
System.out.println(d instanceof Boolean); // true
d = 22; 
d = "hi";       
System.out.println(d instanceof Integer); // false
System.out.println(d instanceof String);  // true
```

[`The Type Comparison Operator instanceof`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

Comment: Use of `instanceof` is a code smell, usually wafting from a flawed type analysis, and tends to create messy, bug-ridden code unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: @Lew, you're 100% correct. But the posted anwser replays the question.

Comment: I would expect a dynamic variable to resolve usage at runtime, like C#'s `dynamic`. That is, `d.foo()` would check at runtime that `d` has a `foo` method.

Comment: There is a difference between run-time typing and dynamic typing. The `Object` strategy described here creates more problems than it solves. You can do what's necessary using generics and run-time type tokens without sacrificing type orientation. This is not a good answer; in fact quite the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at mixing in the groovy language which runs on the JVM. This has type inferrance

Comment: Java has type inference. Type inference is not dynamic typing. Type inference is a strategy for strong typing.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic typing is evil so Java eschewed it. Like Swift and C#, Java is strongly typed, which leads to safer and cleaner code. So give in to the Dark Side and put aside your rebel ways. Embrace the Force of type-oriented programming. You'll be the better for it.

Comment: C# has `dynamic` for dynamic typing. It's useful in some specific scenarios like JSON and interacting with COM.

Comment: I agree, I avoid dynamic everywhere possible, I love strongly typed approach. I just needed to find out about it for some exceptional cases.

Comment: Java handles run-time typing for JSON just fine. You don't need dynamic typing at all for that, @chris

Comment: @shal please describe an "exceptional" case where you need dynamic typing and I'll show you how to solve it in Java with strong typing.

Comment: @LewBloch, it's irrelevant now, I asked a question 3 years ago today 

Comment: Truth remains truth even years later.

Comment: I use an autogenerated JSON parser which aliases various JSON defs into a single type. C#'s `dynamic` beautifully allows me to locally bypass the type system to deal with this. There are other solutions, but all of them are uglier and hackier. I wondered how would I have fixed this in Java, found this answer... and now I'm so glad I'm doing this in C#! Funny how limitations can be praised as features. That won't help Java improve.